# Should I share my trigger.io provisioning profiles and certificates?

Tags: ios, certificate, trigger.io, ios-provisioning

I am using http://trigger.io to build an iOS app. I'm not really clear on how iOS code signing with provisioning profile and certificates work. Can I commit my developer certificate and provisioning profile to source control so that other devs can use them to build?

Answer (score 2):

So what I'm taking from your question is that you are trying to allow fellow team members the ability to sign and place the app on an IOS device correct? If this is what you are looking to do you would have to create a Team Profile and add developers to it within Xcode then also create a provisioning profile for different teams to use to deploy the app.